# How do I create a macro in Excel to hide every other column

Tags: excel, vba

How do I create a macro in Excel to hide every other column

I currently have an Excel spreadsheet with each column representing a particular type of data (i.e artist, album, title) in a music file.

What I would like to do is show changes by having two columns for each type of data (i.e artistOld, artistCurrent, albumOld, albumCurrent, titleOld, titleCurrent) but most of the time user would not want to see the old columns so what I want is a Macro that simply shows/hides the *Old* columns.

BTW I am ware that you can add comments (like tooltips) when you hover over a cell so in theory  this would be a way to store old data, but this is not what I want. I want the user to be able to see all the data at the same time not just the old data for one particular field.

Screenshot without the old value column

[image]

Comment: Would be great if you could share your code you and things that you have already tried.

Comment: Instead of using a macro for this, just use a pivot table. You could move only the columns they need to see into the row fields of the pivot, and refresh it if any changes are made. It will be far easier to maintain than the VBA.

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle, I dont know how to create Macros, the spreadsheet has actually been created programmatically use apache-poi, but I assume this is the kind of thing that can be done with Macros

Comment: Yes it is possible with macros. However, as far as I am aware stackoverflow is not a free coding service :)

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle well it is free, can you at least suggest how I get started

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your sheet?

Comment: @BrandonBarney seems pivot tables a re a way to summarize information that is not what I require.

Comment: Try: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/624991-using-vba-hide-unhide-columns-click-button.html

Comment: @Zac added screenshot

Comment: @PaulTaylor Instead of dismissing it, try it first. I use PivotTables on a daily basis and you can quite literally duplicate your table using a PivotTable. Yes, they are intended for summary, but that doesn't mean that you can't use their functionality for non-summary activities. Further, I can pretty much guarantee that the PivotTable is easier to implement, and will be less-likely to fail.

Comment: @Brandon I just read a tutorial on it, but I don't understand how it helps me

Comment: 1) Enable editing, 2) Record a macro where you manually hide the desired columns, 3) Tweak the resulting *recorded macro code* to satisfy the general use-case.

Comment: Asking a question like "Show me how to do this", without demonstrating any effort, is frowned upon here. Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask] and why it's important to include a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidZemens yes, yes and if it was technology I was familair with I would do just that, but since it is technology I dont know its very difficult to even know where to begin, I didnt even know you could just record macros!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hide all even columns:

```
Sub hiiddee()
    Dim i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For i = 16384 To 2 Step -2
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This is an adaptation of BrandonBarney's idea.  It assumes that the column headers of the columns to be hidden/unhidden contain the string *Old*:

```
Sub BrandonsIdea()
    Dim i As Long, KolKount As Long, r As Range

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
       KolKount = .Columns.Count + .Column - 1
    End With

    For i = 1 To KolKount
        With Cells(1, i)
        If InStr(1, .Value, "Old") > 0 Then
            .EntireColumn.Hidden = Not .EntireColumn.Hidden
        End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Each time it is run, it will toggle hidden/unhidden.

**EDIT#2 General Instructions:**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

**EDIT#3:**

This version will loop over all worksheets:

```
Sub BrandonsIdea_2_The_Sequel()
    Dim i As Long, KolKount As Long, r As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In Sheets
        With sh.UsedRange
           KolKount = .Columns.Count + .Column - 1
        End With

        For i = 1 To KolKount
            With sh.Cells(1, i)
                If InStr(1, .Value, "Old") > 0 Then
                    .EntireColumn.Hidden = Not .EntireColumn.Hidden
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Worth noting that as soon as the ordering is not even/odd, this will hide the wrong columns.

Comment: @BrandonBarney  You are indeed correct! To hide the **odd numbered** columns, the `For` loop limits should be modified.

Comment: You could consider reading the header rows in the range and checking to see if they are `Like "*old*"` since these are the columns that need to be hidden. Even better if the range is a table, you can loop through the header collection itself.

Comment: @BrandonBarney  Reading the headers is a **Great Idea** !................far fewer columns would have to be hidden!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Like '*old' would be good improvement, and does it work over multiple tabs ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @BrandonBarney  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Looks good, I did alt-F11 to create a macro(module), but Cant see how to actually run a macro from the spreadsheet ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor  I added general instructions.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Hi greate it works, but only for the current tab. can it be made to work over all tabs so that the user just has to call it once to toggle on/off instead of doing per tab

Comment: @PaulTaylor  See my **EDIT#3**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent thankyou for the comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in the comments, try the Pivot Table approach first. Don't get me wrong, I love VBA, but I also know that many users on SO will attempt to use VBA for trivial tasks, and these solutions tend to be fragile. I am a huge proponent of learning Excel before VBA.

Here's my sample table. Keep in mind, this is a **table**. If you have structured data it **should be formatted as a table, with a meaningful name**. `CTRL+T` over the selection to format as a table.

[image: Sample Table]

Next, I insert a Pivot Table:

[image: Pivot Table Example]

Let's make it duplicate our table without our extra column:

[image: Pivot Table Example 2]

And make it nice and pretty by going to 'Design', turning off Grand Totals, as well as subtotals. Changing report layout to tabular, and repeating all item labels:

[image]

And Voila! Now I can add whatever I want to my original table and hit the `Refresh` button and it will work beautifully, or I can add/remove columns from my pivot with ease by removing them from rows. I can also add summaries (such as number of songs?) as an aggregate.

Comment: This is a very logical approach!

Comment: Sorry probably being dumb here but I still dont get it, if I provide the customer with  such a spreadsheet containing an old column and a pivot table displaying all this data what they do to switch between showing all old/new columns and just showing new columns ?

Comment: @BrandonBailey ,but the CTRL+T tip is very useful (that is something else I wanted to do), do you think that could be done programmatically, i.e when spreadsheet was originally created it could be displayed as a table ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor If you want them to be able to see all vs just new you could make two pivot tables, or just provide the pivot as well as the raw. If you include an aggregate in the Pivot they can also detail in to see all the raw data.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Yes, you can programmatically add tables, but I would be hesitant to recommend learning VBA with your current level of Excel knowledge. I don't mean that to be rude, I mean it moreso as avoid the mistakes I made. I spent close to a year learning VBA on-the-job and making 'automated' solutions that I later learned could be far more efficiently done with formulas, pivots, etc. I still end up using VBA a fair amount, but I use it to do heavy-lifting that Excel can't do on its own. If I can do it with a formula, I do, because it is far less prone to breaking.

Comment: Hi, no that is fine I have no desire to learn VBA and didnt meant that. When I posted this question I tried to keep it simple but there are other issues at play, the spreadsheet is created programmatically from Java used apache-poi. Now this library doesn't support adding Macros and even if there was a way to do with another tool I'm concerned that if the file has to be saved as .xlsm it wouldnt be open on non windows platforms (such as MacOS). I wonder if I can make it Table with Poi, Pivot tables are supported by Poi so maybe this is the way to go but I don't yet understand your solution !

Comment: @PaulTaylor It truly depends on how automated you need this solution to be. Assuming your user has Excel installed, a `.xlsm` file will open just fine. If they do not, then both my approach, and Gary's will likely fail. There are plenty of ways to do this in VBA, as there are in other languages, but a VBA solution would likely need to live in a `tool` workbook that does the work which outputs a `customer copy` that has the processed form.

Comment: That all said though, the instructions I provided should be sufficient to follow through the entire process. The only thing I didn't show was the literal inserting of the pivot table (which can be done via the insert tab). If you are struggling with the task even with the examples provided by myself and Gary, then I would strongly recommend sharpening your Excel abilities overall (perhaps YouTube tutorials) before tackling VBA. There's a lot that VBA is doing behind the scenes without telling you, and this can get you in trouble quickly if you don't understand the process.

Comment: @BrandonBarney Im nore stuggling with the concept of using pivot tables